# Scala app on Heroku - Boot Timeout

Tags: scala, heroku, timeout

I'm trying to deploy a scala app to heroku but I keep receiving

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

at startup.

I am am binding to the port indicated by the PORT env var. To double check this is the case, after the server starts I make a request from the app to one of my resources using this port and it works fine. There's nothing slow that runs at startup, this all happens within seconds.

Can anyone advise on how I could investigate what is broken?

Thanks

Comment: How does your `Procfile` look? Do you only have a single entry, named `web`? Also, are you using any of the advanced networking features?

Comment: Yes, I've just got the one entry - `web: java -jar build/libs/*.jar`. I'm not using any of the advanced networking features.

Comment: Hi! Any update here? I have the same problem. I'm trying to run spray.io example from https://github.com/spray/spray-template . Logs: 2013-10-13T17:52:53.843443+00:00 app[web.1]: [INFO] [10/13/2013 17:52:53.835] [on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://on-spray-can/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:13127
2013-10-13T17:53:50.821053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Comment: Update: My issue was caused by listening on localhost instead of 0.0.0.0. Everything's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen all the time? It happens to me too, occasionally. Seems it started after I moved my app from US to EU region. Which region is your app in?

It doesn't necessarily means there is something wrong with your app. Might just be that the Dyno it self takes a while to start, if you look at the log you should be able to see how long it takes from the app enters starting to when it starts the JVM. If that time is considerable and it keeps happening, you should contact Heroku support.

Comment: Yes, this happens consistently. Following your comments, I tried it in US and Europe regions but it fails in the same way for both. The dyno only seems to be taking a few seconds to run up the JVM. Things are pointing to it being a problem with my app.

Answer (score 0):

I have given up trying to run up jetty embedded. I'm now building a war and using the jetty-runner. This seems to work. Still a little puzzled but moving on.

My Procfile now looks like:

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/jetty/jetty-runner*.jar --port $PORT build/libs/*.war`

Comment: I run embedded Jetty like with this line in my procfile: "web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar $PORT